# library not found for -lstdc++ in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, opencv

I am using the openCV2.framework in my application. It works fine in the simulator, but is not compiling for iOS devices. It get the following error

```
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added other linking flag also...

Comment: Please post the complete linker command that failed.

Comment: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: library not found for -libc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)  Its working well in simulator.

Comment: i am trying to add openCV2.frame work. i added libstd.dylib file and otherlink(in target) but in ios device gives compile time error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am answer my own question. I solved this problem by add the go to Target -> BuildSettings ->search Path -> library Searchpath

give the correct path of added dynamic library **Path** .

Now it will work

Answer (score 1):

Try using libc++ instead of stdc++.  (lib)std++ went GPLv3, so Apple is pushing libc/c++ instead.

Comment: Thanks to replay but now also gave compile error  ld: library not found for -libc++

Comment: this is the full error clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) ld: library not found for -libc++

Comment: what is the reason to came this compile error its working cool in simulator