# framework not found -ObjC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, linker-errors, xcode9.3

I've tried adding **-Objc** and **-lstdc++** to **Other Linker Flags**. (i using RadaeePDF and this framework is necessary for it). but xcode has error: Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group-> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
i tried solveing this by add/remove radaee framework or other framework in project. even i removed all of pods and reinstall them but error didnt solved.
clean/ rebuild and etc is tried too. 
any idea?

[image: ScreenShot of Error]

Comment: Add more information like XCode version number and which compiler you wnat use(gnu or llvm) will help to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [library not found for -lstdc++ in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934790/library-not-found-for-lstdc-in-xcode)